# Apostrophe with the two columns inner join

Tags: sql

I have this issue that that causes about 30 of my records to not show in my query. Some of the values have an Apostrophe in the company name like O'Grady Tire or Mike's Car Service. I know how to handle the Apostrophe in the WHERE Clause but not in the INNER JOIN Clause

Here is my SQL Statement:

```
SELECT PersonData.FullName,   
       PersonData.CellPhone,   
       PersonData.Email, 
       CompanyData.Department, 
       CompanyData.CompanyName   
FROM PersonData   
INNER JOIN CompanyData ON PersonData.Company_Name = CompanyData.CompanyName
```

Comment: besides you should be joining by a key field (the name can't be the key!! what happens if tomorrow the company name change??) are you sure the problem is that, and no that the string are not exactly the same?

Comment: also please especify the database you are using

Comment: depending on the DB engine, try to use trim on PersonData.Coumpany_Name. Eliminate differences for white space. But I agree that the problem isn't the apostrophe. Something else.

Comment: use a column in where or in INNER JOIN ON clause is sintactically the same

Comment: there is no need to treat the single quotes inside a value in any special way.

Comment: It might be that some of the apostrophes are not apostrophes. Note the difference between `\`` and `'`.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's suggestions I will look at the data again. Maybe I am missing something. Like I said, there is about 30 records with Apostrophe out of 5,200 records.

Comment: Also why the down vote? My question is a good question with an example and a sql statement. What more information can I provide?

Comment: @DanNick Probably because you didn't provide a complete and repeatable problem with example data.  There is nothing wrong with the SQL you provided if the names are the same in both tables.  You didn't mention which flavor of SQL are models.  All of which would probably be needed to help you with your problem which is most likely data related.

Comment: I agree that you should use a unique key to join on instead of a name field.  Data entry people are notorious for garbling names.  If you can, create a unique key field for each possible name and join on that.  It's even worse when Data entry people cut and paste the name into the file.  Sometimes they get invisible control characters in there which will leave you scratching your head why `O Grady` is not equal to `O•Grady`.  (OK... that's not quite invisible, but you get the idea.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you I would have never guessed that by looking at the data.